# How to show multiple progress bars for multiple downloading in android concurrently

Tags: android

How to show multiple progress download in android for multiple downloading concurrently?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm afraid we will not be able to help you since your question is too short and lacks detail. Please read stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Like for any widget. You programmatically add many of them in your view.